# Google Distance Matrix Advanced Pricing

Tags: google-maps

I am currently using Distance Matrix Advanced. This month I used a total of about 3618 requests. The amount I had to pay was $253, on average I had to pay $0.07 per request. Meanwhile on the instruction page the price is only $0.01 per request.

I don't understand how Google calculates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Google Maps Distance Matrix API usage is billed per element

As per the [Pricing documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-and-billing#pricing-for-product) for the Distance Matrix API documentation, the Distance Matrix API is being charged per element **NOT** per request.

Elements are calculated as the number of origins x number of destinations. For example:

If you submit a Distance Matrix request with **2 origins** and **4 destinations**, then the total number of elements will be `2 x 4 = 8`.

That means **on a single request**, 8 elements were generated and you'll be charged $0.08.

If you have any more questions about billing or pricing, please contact support on https://developers.google.com/maps/support#contact-maps-support for better assistance.

Comment: I got it wrong when reading google's developer docs. Now I understand. Thank you!

Comment: @HungQuang If you think the answer helped you solve your issue, please do upvote or accept the answer.

Comment: Please do **not** answer questions that are off-topic on Stack overflow. This website is for programming questions. If a question is not about programming, vote to close it as off-topic and move on. Don't answer it.

Comment: Thanks @MrUpsidown! I just started so I really appreciate your advice. I'll get better next time.